# Why does the JTable change color while clicking?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a simple JTable which shows data and different background colors. Displaying the data and coloring the rows works great with the DefaultTableModel. But if I add a MouseListener to the rows to load something when I click on a row, then the background color disappears. Same if I mark a few rows. I don't need the rows to be marked at all, I just need the color too stay and the MouseEvent to work. Here the relevant code:

```
testcase_table = new JTable() {

            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                    int row, int column) {

                List<Element> cases = element.getChildren();
                int passed = 0;
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

                if (!isRowSelected(row)) {

                    c.setBackground(getBackground());
                    passed = 0;

                    if (row <= running_testcase) {
                        List<Element> teststeps = cases.get(row).getChildren();
                        for (Element teststep : teststeps) {

                            if (teststep.getAttribute("status") != null
                                    && teststep.getAttributeValue("status")
                                            .equals("failed")) {
                                passed++;
                            }
                        }

                        if (passed > 0) {
                            c.setBackground(Color.RED);
                        }

                        if (passed == 0) {

                            c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return c;
            }

        };

        testcase_table.setFocusable(false);
        testcase_table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        testcase_table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
              public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                      JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
                      int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                      //set_values(doc,25);
                      set_teststeps(doc, row);
                    }
                  }
                });

private void DisplayData(List<String> Testcases) {

        aModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
            // setting the jtable read only

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        // setting the column name
        Object[] tableColumnNames = new Object[1];
        tableColumnNames[0] = "TestCases";

        aModel.setColumnIdentifiers(tableColumnNames);
        if (Testcases == null) {

            testcase_table.setModel(aModel);

            return;
        }

        Object[] objects = new Object[1];
        ListIterator<String> lstrg = Testcases.listIterator();
        // populating the tablemodel
        while (lstrg.hasNext()) {
            String newcus = lstrg.next();
            objects[0] = newcus;

            aModel.addRow(objects);
        }

        // binding the jtable to the model
        testcase_table.setModel(aModel);

    }
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `Any ideas?` yes this exactly is job for XxxRenderer, more in Oracle tutorial, then logically everything inside `if (row <= running_testcase) {` breaking those rulles, this is job for XxxTableModel, not code inside XxxRenderer, sure as Andrew Thompson commented corrrectly to post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame and JTable, with hardcoded value for XxxTableModel as local variable

Comment: The selected row in a JTable changes background color to give the user a visual indication of which rows he or she selected.  This is more important when the user is selecting multiple rows.  You would create a TableCellRenderer to override this behavior.